# Remove snapshots using scheduled task running but not removing artifacts

Tags: nexus

I have a nexus server version 2.11.1-01 that has a scheduled task setup to run over our snapshots repo to remove snapshots with the minimum snapshot count set to 3 and a retention of 5 days. The scheduled task is showing that it runs, but when I look through our repository there are as many as 26 snapshots for one artifact gav spanning 6 months.

Is there something not configured correctly or a way to find out why it isn't running correctly?

Comment: Does the job finish successfully?

Comment: Yes and no errors. But when I look into the repository, it has not actually removed any artifacts.

Comment: When you say for one gav .. you actuall mean there are 26 actual snapshot versions (date time stamped deploymennts with iteration numbers) in the same -SNAPSHOT version right?

Answer (score 3):

As reported in [this nexus Jira](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-5685):

> The snapshot remover removes timestamped snapshots within one version
>   folder. It does not remove previous versions of snapshots. Note that
>   it is very common for there to be multiple active versions of
>   snapshots for a given artifact, some being produced by branch builds
>   and others by trunk builds.
>
> The "remove if released" option can be used to clean up all snapshots
>   from a particular version.

Also, as reported in [this other Jira](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-4132), you have to check file naming layout:

> Nexus supports Maven2/3 layout only

If you want to delete multiple versions of an artifact, as reported [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-5220), you have to use REST apis:

> curl -X DELETE -u admin:admin123
>   http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/test/project/1.0/
>
> Or, alternatively you can delete them directly from the repository's
>   local storage on disk. If you delete directly from local storage then
>   use the REST command to rebuild metadata for the affected path:
>
> curl -X DELETE -u admin:admin123
>   http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/metadata/repositories/snapshots/content/com/test/project/
>
> You'll also need to update the search indexes. If you schedule a
>   nightly "update indexes" task it will pick up any changes made
>   directly to the storage area.